# Как вывести соты на диаграмме вороного

Tags: javascript

Очень нужна помощь. Есть код на [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), который выводит диаграмму вороного по введённому количеству точек. При этом координаты точек случайны. Разделение поля считается из метрики. Необходимо изменить код — задать координаты точкам таким образом, что бы получились "соты" - ровные шестиугольники как на картинке. В результате должна выводиться диаграмма как на картинке, где введенные точки это центры шестиугольников. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать или какой цикл использовать что бы расставить точки таким образом. Код того что есть и визуальное представление то что хочу получить прилагаю. Заранее благодарю.

[image: Желаемый результат]

```js
var X = new Array(),
    Y = new Array(),
    C = new Array(); //массивы для хранения координат и цвета
var canvas = document.getElementById("diagramCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function magig() { //по кнопке 
  numPoints = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);
  X = new Array(numPoints); //создается массив
  Y = new Array(numPoints);
  C = new Array(numPoints);
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    X[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    Y[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
    C[i] = randomColor();
  }
  buildDiagram();
}

function randomNumber(max) { //Случайное число для цвета в диапазоне[0;max-1]
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
}

function randomColor() { //Случайный цвет 
  return "#" +
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + //преобразование в 16очное значение
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + //для кр, зел, и син используется значение в диапозоне
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2) //преобразуется в строку и в конец строки, что бы получить двузначное значение
}

function Metric(x, y) { //метрика и формула 
  return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}



function buildDiagram() { //Диаграмма
  var width = canvas.width, //определение ширины и высота конвы
      height = canvas.height;
  var dist1 = dist0 = j = 0, //переменные 
      width1 = width - 2,
      height1 = height - 2;
  context.fillStyle = "white"; //цвет фона 
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var y = 0; y < height1; y++) { //цикл с перебором по всем пикселям конвы по координатам х и у
    for (var x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
      dist0 = Metric(height1, 1); //вычисляется метрика в вызове функции 
      j = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) { // цикл по всем точкам где вычисляется метрика относительно пикселя
        dist1 = Metric(X[i] - x, Y[i] - y);
        if (dist1 < dist0) {
          dist0 = dist1;
          j = i;
        } //условие сравнения с обновлением 
      }
      context.fillStyle = C[j]; //устанавливается цвет пикселя равным цвету точки с индексом 
      context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1); //рисуется пиксель размером
    }
  }
  context.fillStyle = "black"; //рисуются точки размером 3 на 3
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    context.fillRect(X[i], Y[i], 3, 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="points">Количество</label>
<input type="number" id="points" min="1" max="100">
<button onclick="magig()">Построить диаграмму</button>
<canvas id="diagramCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: grey; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 3):

Если расположить точки по сетке получим узор квадратов, но если сдвигать каждую 2 строчку на половину стороны квадрата получим узор шестиугольников:

```js
X = [];
Y = [];
C = []; //массивы для хранения координат и цвета
var canvas = document.getElementById("diagramCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function magig() {
  hexagon_R = 50;
  hexagon_r = Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * hexagon_R; // Необходимо для получения правильного шестиугольника

  X = []; //создается массив
  Y = [];
  C = [];

  for (y = 0; y <= canvas.height / hexagon_r / 2; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= canvas.width / hexagon_R / 2; x++) {
      X.push((x + (y % 2 ? 0 : 0.5)) * hexagon_R * 2);
      Y.push(y * hexagon_r * 2);
      C.push(randomColor());
    }
  }
  buildDiagram();
}

function randomNumber(max) {
  //Случайное число для цвета в диапазоне[0;max-1]
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function randomColor() {
  //Случайный цвет
  return (
    "#" +
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + //преобразование в 16очное значение
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2) + //для кр, зел, и син используется значение в диапозоне
    ("00" + (51 + randomNumber(205)).toString(16)).slice(-2)
  ); //преобразуется в строку и в конец строки, что бы получить двузначное значение
}

function Metric(x, y) {
  //метрика и формула
  return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

function buildDiagram() {
  //Диаграмма
  var width = canvas.width, //определение ширины и высота конвы
    height = canvas.height;
  var dist1 = (dist0 = j = 0), //переменные
    width1 = width - 2,
    height1 = height - 2;
  context.fillStyle = "white"; //цвет фона
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var y = 0; y < height1; y++) {
    //цикл с перебором по всем пикселям конвы по координатам х и у
    for (var x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
      dist0 = Metric(height1, 1); //вычисляется метрика в вызове функции
      j = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
        // цикл по всем точкам где вычисляется метрика относительно пикселя
        dist1 = Metric(X[i] - x, Y[i] - y);
        if (dist1 < dist0) {
          dist0 = dist1;
          j = i;
        } //условие сравнения с обновлением
      }
      context.fillStyle = C[j]; //устанавливается цвет пикселя равным цвету точки с индексом
      context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1); //рисуется пиксель размером
    }
  }
  context.fillStyle = "black"; //рисуются точки размером 3 на 3
  for (var i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
    context.fillRect(X[i], Y[i], 3, 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="magig()">Построить диаграмму</button>
<canvas id="diagramCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="background-color: grey; border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь поняла. Догадывалась про схему расположения, но не знала как реализовать и каким образом посчитать. Все работает отлично, благодарю)